# How to get the main directory path

Tags: php

Suppose I have my code on index.php to return its directory path.
index.php can be anywhere

```
Eg : /var/www/example1/index.php or /var/www/examples/example1/index.php.
```

My code should return example1 and examples/example1 respectively.
I dont know in which directory or inner directories the file is.
I want my code to return it's path.

Comment: Let's suppose we need to see the code as well.

Comment: $parentdir=basename(dirname(__FILE__));
echo $parentdir; //will output 'content'

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I guess you want something like this.

**For absolute path**

```
<?php
$path = getcwd();
echo "This Is Your Absolute Path: ";
echo $path;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
substr(__DIR__, 9);
```

`__DIR__` is the absolute path of the directory of the current file, and `substr` will eliminate `/var/www/`

Comment: I have index.php in /var/www/crm . My other script are in /var/www/scripts/script1.php . In my URL due to MVC structure it is like localhost/crm/index.php?blabla .When I load script1.php from url it should give crm as result and not as crm/scripts